# Angular 4- Session Data Best Practice

Tags: angular, typescript, session, variables, session-variables

I'm developing my first Angular app, with typescript, not using php files until now. But now i want do a login, normally i save the user data in Session variables, using php, after reading some articles i see that there are people who save the data in Local Storage or Session Storage. I wanna now what is the best practice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow , please read thsee https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, i'am new in this, i will read for the next one be better.